# Lightning component error "Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback()"

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning

I've created custom ligtning component, that call apex method. Everything work very well, but when my component loaded data, an error occurr: "Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'config' of undefined]
Callback failed: apex://InvoicesController/ACTION$getInvoices".
Here is my Apex class:

```
public without sharing class InvoicesController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Invoice__c> getInvoices(Id organisedEventId) {
    return [
            SELECT Id,
                    Amount__c,
                    Entry_Description__c,
                    Gross_Amount__c, Name,
                    Is_Accountable__c,
                    Name__c,
                    Organised_Event__c,
                    VAT_Rate__c
            FROM Invoice__c
            WHERE Organised_Event__c = :organisedEventId
    ];
}
}
```

Here is my JavaScript controller:

```
({
onLoadDataSets: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getInvoices(component, event);
}
})
```

And my helper:

```
({
getInvoices: function(component, event){
    var action = component.get("c.getInvoices");
    action.setParams({"organisedEventId": component.get("v.recordId")});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            component.set("v.invoices", response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I thought this wasn't a problem anymore, but try renaming either your helper or your apex controller method (they are the same)

Comment: Also make sure your `organisedEventId` is not null

Comment: Try testing the query using execute anonymous

Comment: What are you binding invoices to? A lot of internal saleforce components have a config attribute. For a test, remove anything that depends on this value (ie an `aura:iteration` for example) and try again. Also try just console logging the output.

Comment: As Caspar mentions on the naming - as seen in the third bullet on this page, make the client and server side method names unique to prevent trouble: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex.htm

Comment: Thanks for all replies. I have removed "name" attribute from all "lightning:input" components, that are inside "aura:iteration" loop and everything works well